# How to set different group indicator images in expandable list view?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

What i want is that i am using a expandable list view and i want to set    different images for each group indicator. For better understanding i am attaching a snapshot. Any help will be appreciable.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group Indicator in `ExpandableListView` does not provide the functionality to customize the icon in each item. So the best solution is to set groupIndicator to null, and add an `ImageView` to the group cell to simulate the effect of a group indicator.